# Gunicorn doesn't respond on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I run a gunicorn server on Heroku with the Django framework, but it doesn't respond and closes a connection.
Everything works fine on my Windows computer using the Djagno development server

Here is my log:

```
2021-01-01T16:13:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-01-01T16:13:39.971142+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 16:13:39 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /
2021-01-01T16:13:41.373082+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=computer-vision-ml.herokuapp.com request_id=fc6bf181-e15b-4506-8fe5-8714c033406f fwd="83.30.65.205" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1402ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-01T16:13:41.376383+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 16:13:41 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21
2021-01-01T16:13:41.934138+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 16:13:41 +0000] [11] [DEBUG] GET /favicon.ico
2021-01-01T16:13:42.949069+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 16:13:42 +0000] [30] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30
2021-01-01T16:13:42.943440+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=computer-vision-ml.herokuapp.com request_id=30a20795-6f0b-463c-ba6d-5e72368cd1fc fwd="83.30.65.205" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1010ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Procfile:

```
web gunicorn ComputerVision.wsgi --timeout 15 --keep-alive 5 --log-level debug
```

Comment: Is that actually your `Procfile`? It doesn't contain a `:` anywhere? Does it work locally if you run via [`heroku local`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-local-processname)?

Comment: Yes it is. I copied this line from the Heroku website and it didn't copy the `:`

Comment: Well, you need the `:` after web: `web: gunicorn ComputerVision.wsgi --timeout 15 --keep-alive 5 --log-level debug`. I'm not confident that this would cause your error, though. Please change it, redeploy, and see if that changes anything.